# What are the structure and meaning of this sentence a lie is a lie is a lie is a lie?

Tags: syntax, meaning, phrases

There is a special sentence in English, e.g. a lie is a lie is a lie, or a dollar is a dollar is a dollar. This kind of structure does not have a verb center. that a dollar is a dollar is a dollar means that the value of a dollar keeps constant no matter how you describe it in the financial field, but to me,  a lie is a lie is a lie seems confusing.

Comment: *a lie is a lie is a lie* can also be bracketed as *"a lie is a lie" is a lie*, because the third *lie* can refer to the part in quotation marks. This is not possible with *dollar*. Does the confusion stem from there?

Comment: "A Dollar Is a Dollar Is a Dollar. Except in Our Minds."  This is a real sentence I have collected. According to context, I can understand this. My confusion lies on the meaning of a lie is a lie is a lie because this one is context independent.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t see how context is more important in one than in the other, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to force them into something parsable (especially the "lie" one, because it makes sense to describe the statement "a lie is a lie" as a lie), as they are usually used, they are not grammatical English sentences.